# kernel 4.9.20-040920-generic with a TCP ACK number incorrect issue

Tags: kernel, tcp-ip

hi all we use tcpdump to capture packets from a TCP receiver site. As the pic shows, TCP ACK number is incorrect:

[image: screenshot]

The kernel we are using is 4.9.20-040920-generic, is this a bug of this kernel version ?

Comment: All sorts of stuff could be happening in the hops between here and there. Can you reproduce the problem locally?

Comment: yes we can ,  the capture file on the receiver site ,  which in the pic is .144,  and the incorrect ACK number is sent by .144 ,   so there is a low rate that problem happen on mid hops

Comment: later , we turn kernel back to 3.13 version , then the issue dismiss .

Comment: can kernel development team see this post ?  i think i need to raise a bug

Comment: any people still watching this post ?